# Weird redirect on taxonomy term edit page

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

When I try to edit taxonomy terms, or delete them, and I click on edit/delete,  it redirects me to that term page instead.

I also have Devel module installed, and when I choose that option in the drop-down menu, it works.

I have tried almost everything.

- URLs are OK; if I inspect the edit/delete buttons, the URL is the expected one. When it redirects me, that URL remains in the browser.
- I thought it was a Drupal core issue. At the time I was using Drupal 8.5.3, but I am still having the problem after updating to Drupal 8.5.5.
- I have removed all my custom modules/theme files (to check if it were my fault).
- I changed the administrative theme from the Seven theme to the Bartik theme.
- I cleared the cache and ran update.php several times.

The problem still remains, and I'm still not sure if it's an issue I have somehow caused, or it's a Drupal core issue.

Did anyone have a similar problem, or know what would be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to edit Taxonomy Term view `/admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term` I'm having issues with editing / deleting / translating taxonomy terms because I've edited `taxonomy_term` view. Disable `taxonomy_term` view and edit/delete should work.

Comment: No I didn't try to edit it, but after I have disabled it, it's working finally! Thank you very much!! It took me hours to solve this one.

Comment: OK, if this is caused by the term view with `/taxonomy/term/%` path then this is connected to this issue: [View with user/% path breaks login/logout on 8.5.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2959370)